# Evaluating an algebraic expression

Tags: prolog

This is a test review question that I am having trouble with. How do you write a method to evaluate an algebraic expression with the operators `plus`, 
   `minus` and `times`. Here are some test queries:

```
simplify(Expression, Result, List)

?- simplify(plus(times(x,y),times(3 ,minus(x,y))),V,[x:4,y:2]).
          V = 14

?- simplify(times(2,plus(a,b)),Val,[a:1,b:5]).
          Val = 12

?- simplify(times(2,plus(a,b)),Val,[a:1,b:(-5)]).
          Val = -8 .
```

All I was given were these sample queries and no other explanation. But I am pretty sure the method is supposed to dissect the first argument, which is the algebraic expression, substituting x and y for their values in the 3rd argument (List). The second argument should be the result after evaluating the expression.

I think one of the methods should be `simplify(V, Val, L) :- member(V:Val, L).`
Ideally there should only be 4 more methods... but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: have you written any code you can display?  Its not the practice of this community to write code for people.

Comment: @Brad Other than the one method I wrote, no. This is a test review question and still stumped as to how to go about this. I get more and more confused as I think about it... A push towards the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to want to recursively invoke simplify with the left and right expression trees, and combine those values appropriately using the structure name (times, plus, etc.). You'll pass the variable list along to each of those invocations. That's all the hint I can really give from the confines of the comment box.

Answer (score 2):

Start small, write down what you know.

```
simplify(plus(times(x,y),times(3 ,minus(x,y))),V,[x:4,y:2]):- V = 14.
```

is a perfectly good start: `(+ (* 4 2) (* 3 (- 4 2))) = 8 + 3*2 = 14`. But then, of course,

```
simplify(times(x,y),V,[x:4,y:2]):- V is 4*2.
```

is even better. Also,

```
simplify(minus(x,y),V,[x:4,y:2]):- V is 4-2.
simplify(plus(x,y),V,[x:4,y:2]):- V is 4+2.
simplify(x,V,[x:4,y:2]):- V is 4.
```

all perfectly good Prolog code. But of course what we really mean, *it becomes apparent*, is

```
simplify(A,V,L):- atom(A), getVal(A,L,V).
simplify(C,V,L):- compound(C), C =.. [F|T], 
  maplist( simp(L), T, VS),       % get the values of subterms
  calculate( F, VS, V).           % calculate the final result

simp(L,A,V):- simplify(A,V,L).    % just a different args order
```

etc. `getVal/3` will need to retrieve the values somehow from the `L` list, and `calculate/3` to actually perform the calculation, given a symbolic operation name and the list of calculated values.

Study [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist%2F3) and [`=../2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2).

(not finished, not tested).

---

OK, `maplist` was an overkill, as was `=..`: all your terms will probably be of the form `op(A,B)`. So the definition can be *simplified* to

```
simplify(plus(A,B),V,L):-
  simplify(A,V1,L),
  simplify(B,V2,L),
  V is V1 + V2.         % we add, for plus

simplify(minus(A,B),V,L):-
  % fill in the blanks
  .....
  V is V1 - V2.         % we subtract, for minus

simplify(times(A,B),V,L):-
  % fill in the blanks
  .....
  V is .... .           % for times we ...

simplify(A,V,L):-
  number(A),
  V = .... .            % if A is a number, then the answer is ...
```

and the last possibility is, `x` or `y` etc., that satisfy `atom/1`.

```
simplify(A,V,L):-
  atom(A),
  retrieve(A,V,L).
```

So the last call from the above clause could look like `retrieve(x,V,[x:4, y:3])`, or it could look like `retrieve(y,V,[x:4, y:3])`. It should be a straightforward affair to implement.