# Prolog - evaluating algebraic expressions

Tags: prolog

This is a test review question that I am having trouble with. How do you write a method to evaluate an algebraic expression with the operators 'plus', 'minus' and 'times'. Here are some test queries:

simplify(Expression, Result, List)

`?- simplify(plus(times(x,y),times(3 ,minus(x,y))),V,[x:4,y:2]). V = 14`

`?- simplify(times(2,plus(a,b)),Val,[a:1,b:5]). Val = 12`

`?- simplify(times(2,plus(a,b)),Val,[a:1,b:(-5)]). Val = -8`

All I was given were these sample queries and no other explanation. But I am pretty sure the method is supposed to dissect the first argument, which is the algebraic expression, substituting x and y for their values in the 3rd argument (List). The second argument should be the result after evaluating the expression.

I think one of the methods should be simplify(V, Val, L) :- member(V:Val, L). Ideally there should only be 4 more methods... but I'm not sure how to go about this.

What I have so far but I don't know what the body should be:

```
simplify(Var, Value, Lst) :- member(Var:Value, Lst).
simplify(plus(Var), Value, Lst) :- 
simplify(minus(Var), Value, Lst) :-
simplify(times(Var), Value, Lst) :-
```

I am not sure what the 5th method should be.

Comment: Sure seems similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150232/evaluating-an-algebraic-expression) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've allowed yourself to get snowed by complex examples. You're just missing one base case and all the inductive cases are really simple. You just need some simpler examples. For starters, what should this return?

```
?- simplify(3, Val, []).
```

Yeah, `Val = 3`. So let's add that missing base case:

```
simplify(Num, Num, _) :- number(Num).
```

The key insight to the inductive casess is that `plus`, `minus` and `times` all have the same recursive binary structure. You can recursively apply `simplify` to both sides to achieve to evaluate things. Let's try another simple example:

```
?- simplify(times(3, 3), Val, []).
```

We want `Val = 9`. All we need to do is figure out what the left and right values are and multiply them together. So it will wind up looking like this:

```
simplify(times(Left, Right), Value, Lst) :-
  simplify(Left, LeftVal, Lst),
  simplify(Right, RightVal, Lst),
  Value is LeftVal * RightVal.
```

You want to pass `Lst` on to the recursive invocations so they can look up variables too. From here you should be able to extrapolate what the `plus` and `minus` cases are going to look like. You really shouldn't need cases that look like `plus(X)` since that only has one argument.

The magic of Prolog is that this is really all you have to do. Recursion will take care of your complex examples as soon as you have the simple ones working. Try it. :)

Hope this helps!