# Prolog - evaluation arbitrarily sized expressions

Tags: recursion, prolog

The function is meant to evaluate an arbitrarily structured expression with references to a list of variables. (I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150232/evaluating-an-algebraic-expression) exists, but its answer is poorly written and I cannot understand it.)

My work so far is below:

```
lookup(X, Env, V) :-
    member(val(X,V),Env). //finds the value of a variable in the "environment".

eval(S, Env, V):-
    lookup(S,Env,V). //if expression is a single variable name/key, return the value of the pair.

eval(H+T, Env, V):- //if expression is in the form of head+tail...
    lookup(H,Env,HVal), //first, make sure that the head can be looked up;
    eval(T, Env, V - HVal). //then, treat the tail as its own expression while expecting a modified value.
eval(F+S, Env, V):- //if expression is contains two atoms, evaluate their sum.
    lookup(F, Env, FVal),
    lookup(S, Env, SVal),
    V is FVal + SVal.

... % minus, times etc. implemented similarly
```

Right now, the code works fine for single-value look up like:

```
?- eval(a, [val(a,1),val(b,2),val(c,3)], V).
V = 1 .
```

As well as "diatomic" expressions:

```
?- eval(a+b, [val(a,1),val(b,2),val(c,3)], V).
V = 3 .
```

but more than that (i.e. `a+b+a`) makes the code return `false.` instantly.

What's wrong with my implementation? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think your main problem is expecting `V - HVal` in the goal `eval(T, Env, V - HVal)` to do something. Without trying it, I think you want to change that line of code to `eval(T, Env, TVal), V is HVal + TVal.`.

Comment: By the way, I think Will's answer on that question is great and worthy of serious study. I think you're misattributing your confusion at Prolog. Confusion is a normal part of learning--if you weren't confused, you would be having an encounter with something you already understand.

Comment: call `eval` recursively on the subexpressions.

Comment: Where are the [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) clauses to differentiate the two predicates `eval(H+T, Env, V)` and `eval(F+S, Env, V`? Your second predicate says `if expression is contains two atoms` but I see no guard clauses checking to make sure that `F` and `S` are atoms.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don't think they need two clauses here if they follow Willem's advice.

Comment: @DanielLyons You could be right, I just don't have the time to test this question out. I have an evaluation system that has many 10s of rules and the guards are needed.

Comment: @GuyCoder fair enough

Comment: Of interest: PRESS: PRolog Equation Solving System [GitHub](https://github.com/maths/PRESS)